# Converting a range of IPv4 addresses to netmasks using bash

Tags: command-line, networking, bash

I have an input file with IPv4 addresses:

```
94.228.16.0 - 94.228.25.255
94.241.136.0/24
94.241.136.0 - 94.241.136.255
94.29.128.0/17
94.29.128.0 - 94.29.191.0
94.29.192.0 - 94.29.255.0
94.74.181.0/24
94.74.181.0 - 94.74.181.31
94.74.181.128 - 94.74.181.255
```

How I can convert the address ranges to netmasks?
The result should be:

```
94.228.16.0/21
94.241.136.0/24
94.241.136.0/24
94.29.128.0/17
94.29.128.0/19
94.29.192.0/19
94.74.181.0/24
94.74.181.0/27
94.74.181.128/25
```

Comment: Several of the results you ask for are incorrect, so no valid bash script will produce them. For instance, the first range is not expressible using a netmask: 94.228.16.0/21 gives 94.228.16.0 - 94.228.23.255, and the next wider 94.228.16.0/20 gives 94.228.16.0 - 94.228.31.255. Also, ranges ending in .0 cannot be produced by any netmask.

Comment: @Zanna you're cheating, the poster asked _using bash_. My bash has no `ipcalc` builtin. ;-)

Comment: @zwets ah I've figured it out! But you're right, the shell needs a lot of help hahaha

Answer (score 14):

First you will need to install a package to do the conversion

```
sudo apt install ipcalc
```

Now you can do it with this little script (please note that it doesn't work if you quote the variable):

```
$ while read line; do if [[ $line = *-* ]]; then (ipcalc $line | sed '2!d'); else echo $line; fi; done < file
94.228.16.0/21
94.241.136.0/24
94.241.136.0/24
94.29.128.0/17
94.29.128.0/19
94.29.192.0/19
94.74.181.0/24
94.74.181.0/27
94.74.181.128/25
```

or more readably

```
while read line; do
   if [[ $line = *-* ]]; then 
     (ipcalc $line | sed '2!d')
   else echo $line
   fi
done < file
```

Comment: @Oleksii always a pleasure :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not surprisingly, there is a CPAN perl module [Net::CIDR](http://search.cpan.org/~mrsam/Net-CIDR-0.11/CIDR.pm) for this.

So for example:

```
$ perl -MNet::CIDR=range2cidr -lne 'print for range2cidr $_' yourfile
94.228.16.0/21
94.228.24.0/23
94.241.136.0/24
94.241.136.0/24
94.29.128.0/17
94.29.191.0/32
94.29.128.0/19
94.29.160.0/20
94.29.176.0/21
94.29.184.0/22
94.29.188.0/23
94.29.190.0/24
94.29.255.0/32
94.29.192.0/19
94.29.224.0/20
94.29.240.0/21
94.29.248.0/22
94.29.252.0/23
94.29.254.0/24
94.74.181.0/24
94.74.181.0/27
94.74.181.128/25
```

The module is available on Ubuntu by installing the `libnet-cidr-perl` package.

***NB*** I have **not** validated your input or the results.

Comment: It's noteworthy that this supports IPv6, where ipcalc does not.